# Jenkins Startup a Command Line Executable

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins, xcode-server

I'm new to Jenkins and i'm trying to setup a CI pipeline for a macOS Server / iOS environment. My environment integrates with Xcode server and one of the things I want to do is run a command line application that talks to Xcode server API and processes the last set of integrations. My command line application works properly when invoked in the terminal but I would like Jenkins to be able to invoke this as one of the build steps.

My execute shell build step looks like this:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

security unlock-keychain -p ${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k ${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}
xcrun xcodebuild clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=${PROVISIONING_PROFILE} OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}"

sh /usr/local/bin/my-command-line-app
```

The build is successful but fails when trying to invoke the command line app.

The error I get from the jenkins console is:

```
cannot execute binary file
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Now I have placed this executable in 2 locations both of which failed.

```
1. sh /usr/local/bin/my-command-line-app
2. sh /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/my-command-line-app
```

I also tried `chmod +x to the my-command-line-app` to try and change the permissions but this still results in the same error.

If anyone has any tips on how to configure this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but does it work if you invoke your application directly instead of using the `sh `?

Comment: Oh wow, so simple, that worked for me. If you want to propose that as an answer I will gladly accept it :)